# Roslibjs for a client to communicate with simple action Server

Tags: ros, action-server, roslibjs, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I made a simple action server and client guided by the tutorials, I was able to make everything work. I wanted to take one step more and try to make the action client using `roslibjs`, then this Error came up:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1424105276.754999] Client connected.  1 clients total.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424105276.766179] [Client 0] [id: advertise:/control/goal:1] advertise: gamma/src/control/ControlActionGoal is not a valid type string
[INFO] [WallTime: 1424105276.921603] [Client 0] Subscribed to /control/status
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424105276.925383] [Client 0] [id: subscribe:/control/feedback:4] subscribe: gamma/src/control/ControlActionFeedback is not a valid type string
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424105276.930062] [Client 0] [id: subscribe:/control/result:5] subscribe: gamma/src/control/ControlActionResult is not a valid type string
```

I think that this Error is associated to the `actionName` field when `ROSLIB.ActionClient` is called.
The route to the .action file is: ~/Desktop/gamma/src/control/Control.action

The html file with the client is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>                                                                
<html>                                                                        
<head>                                    
  <title> Control client </title>                                                              
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" type="text/javascript">

  //connect to ROS
  var ros = new ROSLIB.Ros({ url: 'ws://localhost:9090' });

  //emit the error on the backend if exist
  ros.on('error', function(error) {
    document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'inline';
    console.log(error);
  });

  // Find out exactly when we made a connection.
  ros.on('connection', function() {
    console.log('Connection made!');
    document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('error').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'inline';
  });

  ros.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed.');
    document.getElementById('connecting').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('connected').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('closed').style.display = 'inline';
  });

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  //Action Client
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                          
                                                                                               
  // Conect to the server on charge of the mobile control of the turtlebot                     
  var controlClient = new ROSLIB.ActionClient({                                                
    ros : ros,
    serverName: '/control',
    actionName: 'gamma/src/control/ControlAction'                                      
  });                                                                                          

  //Created function to move foward the turtlebot                                              
  function pubMessage() {
    //Create the variable that will be associated to the goal                                  
    var twist = new ROSLIB.Message ({                                                          
      linear : {                                                                               
        x : 0.1,                                                                               
        y : 0.0,                                                                               
        z : 0.0 
      },
      angular : { 
        x : 0.0,                                                                               
        y : 0.0, 
        z : 0.0
      }                                                                                        
    });                                    
   //Create the goal
    var goal = new ROSLIB.Goal({
      actionClient : controlClient,
      goalMessage : twist 
    });

    //Send the goal to the server to execute the callbacks
    goal.send();
    console.log("Goal sent forward");
    return true;
  }
  </script>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="statusIndicator">
    <p id="connecting">
      Connecting to rosbridge...
    </p>
    <p id="connected" style="color:#00D600; display:none">
      Connected
    </p>
    <p id="error" style="color:#FF0000; display:none">
      Error in the backend!
    </p>
    <p id="closed" style="display:none">
      Connection closed.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div> <button id="forward" type="action" onclick="pubMessage()">Forward</button> </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The error is reported in the `rosbridge` terminal and the server name associated to the client is right

**Update:**

The server is writed with roscpp and the client using roslibjs

Changing the action name to `control/ControlAction` converts this problem to another:

```
[INFO] [WallTime: 1424162821.801547] Client connected.  1 clients total.
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424162821.811618] [Client 4] [id: advertise:/control/goal:1] advertise: Unable to load the manifest for package control. Caused by: control
[INFO] [WallTime: 1424162821.824552] [Client 4] Subscribed to /control/status
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424162821.830844] [Client 4] [id: subscribe:/control/feedback:4] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package control. Caused by: control
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1424162821.837860] [Client 4] [id: subscribe:/control/result:5] subscribe: Unable to load the manifest for package control. Caused by: control
```

in the terminals are already sourced: `devel/setup.bash`

What could be this new error related to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203218/roslibjs-for-a-client-to-communicate-with-simple-action-server/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-02-17**:
Is your action server set up correctly? That is, are you able to call the action natively in ROS?

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-17**:
yes, the action server is working and I am able to call the action natively in ROS (I did it changing the Tutorials)

**Comment by [Johan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21880/johan/) on 2015-03-21**:
Is there a specific folder that the HTML file needs to be saved ? Don't get me wrong, I am not very familiar with ROS. Usually I use a web server , which there is a folder to place it. When I am running the server so I will be able to call the HTML via localhost as an example.

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-03-23**:
The HTML can be hosted anywhere, it is independent of the ROS system. The client will make a connection to ROS via rosbridge over websockets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The actionName won't be a path.. I think it will be just the root name of the action type; in this place "Control", or if that isn't unique then the package_name/action_name (control/Control). Then rosbridge will have to find that action. So make sure that the control package is built, and you've sourced the devel/setup.bash in the workspace where you built it before you run rosbridge. If you need help building your ros workspace, see this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2015-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-17**:
Already sourced, and the problem continue. I tried your sugesstion but that made a `Unable to load the manifest for package control` error, I have modified my qustion

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-02-17**:
What is the actual package name and is the package.xml file defined correctly? Can you post it somewhere?